# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str! Help please

Tags: python, string, concatenation

I am new here I hope you will try to help me, I tried to code this with python but when I run a get this error, can anyone tel me what to do please ? Can you fix my code ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/mycode.py", line 62, in <module>
    my_file.run()
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/mycode.py", line 45, in run
    command = self.reliable_receive()
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/mycode.py", line 22, in reliable_receive
    json_data = 'json_data' + self.connection.recv(1024)
```

This is another code as a review for you.
When the client tries to execute my program it says

```
Unhandled exception in script.
Failed to execute script "client_s" due to unhandled exception: can only concatenate str(not "bytes") to str
Traceback(most recent call last):
file "client_s.py" line 61, in <module>
file "client_s.py" line 45, in run
file "client_s.py" line 22, in reliable_receive
Type error: can only concatenate str(not bytes) to str
```

This is line 61
my_file = File("192.168.1.70", 4858)

```
line 45:
43 def run(self):
44      while True:
45          command = self.reliable_receive()
46          if command[0] == "exit":
47              self.connection.close()
48              exit()
```

```
18 def reliable_receive(self):
19      json_data = ""
20      while True:
21          try:
22              json_data = json_data + self.connection.recv(1024)
23              return json.loads(json_data)
24          except ValueError:
25              continue
```

Comment: There's not enough code to say what exactly is wrong here. You would need to create a reproducible example. However, your error message suggests you're trying to append text and some kind of object that doesn't have a text representation. json_data = 'json_data' (text) + self.connection.recv(1024) (not text).

Comment: It's not clear to me what that line is supposed to be doing. Perhaps you wanted `json_data = json_data + self.connection.recv(1024)` (without the quotation marks)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre], and show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error along with code that produces that exact error. Keep in mind that we need a *specific* question; "can you fix my code please?" [does not qualify](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236), as this is **not a discussion forum**. That said, this looks like a simple typo. `'json_data'` means the actual text (lowercase j, lowercase s, etc.), rather than the existing variable with that name.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into a decoding problem. The `recv` method will return `bytes`, but you are trying to append it to a `str`. Decode the bytes to transform it into `str`. Since the variable says "json" we can assume it's UTF-8, so:

```
json_data = "json_data" + self.connection.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
```

(but that won't actually be valid JSON).

Comment: This is almost certainly not what OP wants. My best guess is that OP is accumulating raw data from a socket into an existing variable with `bytes` data, for later processing. This is itself probably the wrong idea, but the simplest explanation of the provided error is that `'json_data'` was intended to be the variable `json_data` instead. Regardless - I should not have to explain this to a seasoned user, but we should not try to give answers when neither the problem nor the question is clear. Please read [answer] as a refresher.

Comment: Hard to tell what the intent is, but I see it as an opportunity to explain the need for decoding bytes if you want text (str).

Comment: We have countless duplicates for that already.